# How to read array from html to js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I declare an array with json data, then when I `init` the array should be read and display on the div.
But now show nothing, can anyone help me check my code, what mistake I have made. Thanks.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qnhcudp/)

**HTML**

```
<script>
$(function() {


    var array = [];
    array[0] = {
        "no": "1",
            "name": "fruit",
            "value": "mango",
            "totalvote": "75"
    };
    array[1] = {
        "no": "2",
            "name": "fruit",
            "value": "apple",
            "totalvote": "10"
    };
    array[2] = {
        "no": "3",
            "name": "fruit",
            "value": "orange",
            "totalvote": "5"
    };
    array[3] = {
        "no": "4",
            "name": "fruit",
            "value": "banana",
            "totalvote": "45"
    };

    PG.init("popup_survey_whitebox_selection", "1", array);
    PG.callpopup();
    PG.render_1();

});
</script>
```

**JS**

```
    var PG = {
    divid: "",
    multiselection: "",
    optionitem: [],
    /*  type:"",        */
    init: function (divid, multiselection, optionitem) {
        /*     PG.type = type;*/
        PG.divid = divid;
        PG.multiselect = multiselection;
        PG.optionitem = optionitem;
    },
    test: function () {
        for (var i = 0; PG.optionitem.length > i; i++) {
            alert(PG.optionitem[i].name);
        }
    },
    callpopup: function () {
        $("#popup_survey_whitebox_content").hide();

        var orig = '', // create var to cache the original text
            newText = ''; // create var to cache the new Text with "..."

        $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(function (index, currentText) {
            orig = currentText;
            newText = currentText.substr(0, 30);

            if (currentText.length > 30) newText += "...";

            return newText;
        });

        $("#popup_survey_whitebox").hover(function () {
            $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').stop().animate({
                opacity: 1,
                height: "toggle"
            }, 500, function () {

                $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(orig); // Here put the original text.

            }).css('position', 'relative');

        }, function () {
            $('#popup_survey_whitebox_content').stop().animate({
                opacity: 1,
                height: "toggle"
            }, 500, function () {
                $("label#popup_survey_label_title").text(newText); // Here put the new text with "..."

            }).css('position', 'relative');
        });

        $("#popup_survey_end_whitebox").click(function () {
            $("#popup_survey_whitebox").remove();
        });



    },
    render_1: function () {

        $.each(array, function (i, obj) {
            if (PG.multiselect == 1) {
                var selection = "<li class='popup_survey_whitebox_li'></li><input class='the_checkbox' type='radio' id=" + obj.value + " name=" + obj.name + " value=" + obj.value + ">" +
                    "<label class='popup_survey_whitebox_label' for=" + obj.value + ">" + obj.no + ". " + obj.value + "</label>" +
                    "<div class='popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar'><div class='popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner' for=" + obj.value + " style='width:" + obj.totalvote + "%;'>" +
                    "</div></div>" +
                    "<div id='popup_survey_whitebox_percent' class='popup_survey_whitebox_percent'>" + obj.totalvote + "%</div>";

            } else {
                var selection = "<li class='popup_survey_whitebox_li'></li><input class='the_checkbox' type='checkbox' id=" + obj.value + " name=" + obj.name + " value=" + obj.value + ">" +
                    "<label class='popup_survey_whitebox_label' for=" + obj.value + ">" + obj.no + ". " + obj.value + "</label>" +
                    "<div class='popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar'><div class='popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar_inner' for=" + obj.value + " style='width:" + obj.totalvote + "%;'>" +
                    "</div></div>" +
                    "<div id='popup_survey_whitebox_percent' class='popup_survey_whitebox_percent'>" + obj.totalvote + "%</div>";
            }
            $("#" + PG.divid).append(selection);


        });
        var survey_button = "<br><input id='submit_btn' type='button' class='whiteboxbutton whiteboxbutton-small' value='Finish' style='width:100%;'>";

        $("#popup_survey_label_title").append("What is your favorite fruit??What is your favorite fruit??");
        /*$("#popup_survey_whitebox_title").append();*/
        $("#popup_survey_whitebox_inner_title").append("Please select 1 fruit only:");
        $('#popup_survey_whitebox_button').append(survey_button);


        $('.the_checkbox').on('change', function (evt) {
            $('.popup_survey_whitebox_percent').css('display', 'block');
            $('.popup_survey_whitebox_progressbar').css('display', 'block');
            $(".popup_survey_whitebox_button").show();
            if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= PG.multiselect) {
                this.checked = false;

            }
        });

    },


    save: function () {}
}
```

I console and get this error **Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined** but I must declare on html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). There is a couple of different things you could do but simply, you can just move your array declaration outside of the closure.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qnhcudp/1/)

```
<script>
var array = [];
$(function() {

    ...
});
</script>
```

---

Found another solution to your problem, your `PG` object is actually trying to reference the global scope where it doesn't need to. See, your inline script where you declare the array, you are passing that into the `PG` object.

You have this:

```
render_1: function () {
    $.each(array, function (i, obj) {
        ...
    });
}
```

Replace with this:

```
render_1: function () {
    $.each(PG.optionitem, function (i, obj) {
        ...
    });
}
```

This solution is actually independant from my first one. If you don't want the array in global scope, this solution will work.

Comment: hi, thanks u so much . Now it show but another problem come out, u can see the `callpopup` function, before I was put those code in document ready function, but my friend say should put inside the `PG` so can `init` easily, but when I put inside it affecting already.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand you. The fiddle I have linked to in my answer show your code working now. I did modify your code so the javascript is included in the `head` tag rather than wrapped in a ready or onload event.

Comment: as in ur updated jsfiddle, when hover the div the text suddenly disappear. Before I put in `document ready function` the title if longer will show `...`, then when hover only show back the full title, now put in `PG` why affected ? did u know the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

There is other way around as well to solve this error besides `closure`. Since, you already have `optionitem` present in `PG` and you already passed the `optionitem` to it, you can use it as well inside `render_1` method.

Change

```
$.each(array, function (i, obj) {
```

to

```
$.each(PG.optionitem, function (i, obj) {
```

With that, you need not to define `array` as a global variable which might conflict with others.

http://jsfiddle.net/5qnhcudp/2/

Comment: Haha, was just editing my answer as I noticed the same thing. +1

Comment: Not an issue @Turnerj :)